# Changing Encrypted Password (Ruby On Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to implement a "change password" function on my website.

I have the following in my user.rb

```
before_save :encrypt_password

  def encrypt_password
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt
    string
  end

  def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
  end

  def encrypt_password
    self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
    self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
  end

  def encrypt(string)
    secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
  end

  def make_salt
    secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
  end

  def secure_hash(string)
    Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return nil if user.nil?
    return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
 end
```

When creating an account, the user has to type in name, email, password and password_confirmation, but if I go into rails console and look up the table it has a **encrypted_password**, instead of password and password_confirmation.

When I get the input from the user (passed by a form), I did:

```
 @user.update_attributes(:password => params[:password][:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password][:password_confirmation])
 @user.save
```

but this is not working! I wonder if I need to decrypt the old password and encrypt the new one in order to get it updated... any insight? Thanks for your time!

Comment: I know next to nothing about Ruby, but what do you my by decrypt the old password?  Do you mean, retrieve the password from the hashed password?

Comment: is that your entire user.rb file?  do you have attr_accessible :password, :password_confirmation and attr_accessor :password in there to define the attributes on the model?  what error messages do you get when trying to save?

Answer (score 0):

if i were you, i will use what have been already created and go for:

[authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)
or

[device](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)